# Lex bots are not populating in Amazon Connect Instance

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

We have created a bot and published and trying to invoke from Amazon Connect instance. Lex bots are not populating in the drop down. Is there any configuration change we need to do?

[image: Customer Input Lex Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the bot to your Amazon Connect instance before you can make use of it in your contact flow. This is done in the Amazon Connect instance configuration within the AWS console (not the Connect UI). See the section called “Add the Amazon Lex bot to your Connect instance” in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/amazon-lex.html) doc for specific steps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have created an alias for lex bot and then add it to your connect instance e.g. connect -> instance -> contact flows-> Amazon Lex -> Add amazon lex bot.

and than you're able to use it in your contact flows.

[image]